# Is there any grammatical passive that applies to nouns?

Tags: noun, passive

I was trying to translate the following (technical) phrase:

> visualisation of light passing through a birefringent material

...and I came up with this:

> Visualisierung von die Übertragung polarisiertes Licht durch ein doppelbrechendes Material

a friend of mine criticized this on the grounds that "that is *passiv*, there is no verb so no movement, you are supposed to use dative with a noun + *durch*". His version was:

> Visualisierung der Übertragung vom polarisierten Licht durch doppelbrechendem Material

The only *Passiv* I am familiar with is the one that involves `werden + Partizip II`, e.g. "Er wurde von mir gefragt.", so I was confused.

The question is: does any *Passiv* exist that applies to this case, and what would be the correct translation for this phrase?

Comment: I don't see much of a difference between the two versions, they are both rather broken. I also have difficulty understanding what it is you want to know here. Generally speaking, nouns and participles derived from a verb can have an active or passive meaning; e.g. a _beleuchtendes Objekt_ is something that casts light on something else, whereas a _beleuchtetes Objekt_ receives light from elsewhere.

Comment: 1) *durch* induces always accusative, that's not questionable.
2) That's not a sentence. There is no verb in the English example (the gernud would be rather translated as *links Attributiv*)

Comment: My first thought was that maybe your friend had the so-called [Nominalstil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalstil) in mind and that you could make this phrase more understandable or so if you didn't use nouns like "Visualisierung" and "Übertragung" but verbs like "visualisieren" and "übertragen" (thus leading to a complete reconstruction of the sentence.)

Comment: Wo kommt das "polarisiert" her? Wenn es für die Fragestellung nicht notwendig ist würde ich es weg lassen und die Phrase möglichst einfach halten. Später die Polarisation an der richtigen Stelle einzufügen sollte ein leichtes sein.

Comment: Yes, where does the _polarisiert_ come from? Furthermore I assume (correct me if I'm wrong), that light here is __not__ polarized __before__ passing through the birefringent material. If so, all current translation attempts are misleading.

Comment: ... except the one by @userunknown. The reason why I assume the incident light not to be polarized is that birefringent materials are used to split unpolarized light into two beams of orthogonal polarization, which are refracted differently.

Comment: @WalterTross: Not that this is a place for a discussion about physics, but birefringent materials may also be used to alter the polarization of light that's already polarized (e.g. linear to elliptic etc.)

Comment: @neuviemeporte: correct. I am assuming a didactic setup, because otherwise I see no need to "visualize" the light. Of course a "pre-polarization" could be used to the purpose of the visualization, but _polarized_ is missing in the English text, so that "before" the visualization I don't assume the incident light to be polarized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see a passive form in your English sentence. However, there's a present active participle ("passing"). In principle, one could translate this literally, because German also has these participles, but this is stylistically very awkward. So it's much better to use "bei + *noun (dative)*":

> Visualisierung von polarisierte**m** Licht beim Durchgang durch ein doppelbrechendes Material

assuming that the original sentence should read "visualisation of **polarized** light..."

"Übertragung" means something like "transfer" and doesn't fit here.

And no, there's no passive form for nouns, neither in German nor in English. However, "durch + *noun (accusative)*" is used to describe the agent or instrument in a passive sentence (English "by"). Maybe that is what your friend meant? But "durch" can also be used in the sense of "through", and in "durch ein Material" it is used in the latter sense, not in the former.

Comment: As a physicist I would confirm that it is indeed "doppelbrechend" as the original poster used it, not "doppel**t**brechend". (Otherwise 1+.)

Comment: @Emil: edited accordingly.

Comment: As a former physicist I don't think that _Übertragung_ (here: _transmission_) does not fit. It may not be the best choice for the translation, but it's not incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

> durch doppelbrechendem Material

is kinda weird. A mix of both should be fine, if you translated the words themselve correctly.

> Visualisierung der Übertragung vom polarisierten Licht durch doppelbrechendes Material

Comment: "durch doppelbrechendem Material" ist not only weird, it's wrong, because "durch" requires the accusative.

Answer (score 2):

Just some additional infos on the two translations:

From Paul

> vom polarisierten Licht -> this means there is only one polarized light on the world
>
> von polarisiertem Licht -> polarized light in general

From dirkt:

> durch ein doppeltbrechendes Material - one special birefringent material that was used
>
> durch doppeltbrechendes Material - any birefringent material in general

"Übertragung durch" sounds weird "Übertragung in .. einem Medium" would sound better.

So assuming the theory/thesis applies to any light and any birefringent material it would be:

> Visualisierung der Übertragung von polarisiertem Licht in doppeltbrechendem Material

And now it depends if you are visualizing the transfer or the light, this works too:

> Visualisierung von polarisiertem Licht in doppeltbrechendem Material

I am sorry that I don't know if it is passive+dativ, maybe someone can edit that in, making the answer community wiki.

Comment: I understood "through a birefringent material" to mean one particular material (hence "ein ... Material"), otherwise I would have expected "through birefringent materials" (i.e. any material in general)

Answer (score 2):

```
Q: visualisation of light passing through a birefringent material
```

Das Hantieren mit "von" lenkt nur vom Genitiv ab.

> Visualisierung der Lichtübertragung durch ein doppelbrechendes
>   Material

Die Lichtübertragung wird sichtbar dargestellt. Darstellung des Lichts, nicht von dem Licht. Letzteres hört man zwar oft, ist aber schwacher Stil.